# How to detect style of text in an image using opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv

Currently i am working on opencv. I have an image with a text. And i want to find out the style(Bold, Italic) of the text. How can i achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is (assuming a letter by letter approach)

- Using segmentation techniques you first segment out the letters
- Using the segmented letters,compare against your owns data set of pre-segmented/pre-filtered letters to find the font style.
- Comparison can be done using various features, SIFT,SURF,BRISK,Harris corners, template matching, or your come up with something of your own. My best guess would be to go with HAAR-features and training.
- Once you get a set of features for a letter, matching for closest candidate against your pre-filtered dataset can be achieved using different techniques such as KNN, euclidean distance, etc If you use HAAR features, OpenCV can help alot in retrieval.

Eventually you might ending doing some OCR which includes font style.

OpenCV has a set of built in feature descriptors which you can read [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/table_of_content_features2d/table_of_content_features2d.html)

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot wajih. I will chk this. Is there any other way available to find out the font style of text?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you, I know it's not exact. But it will suffice for my similar project.
"Typefont is an experimental library that detects the font of a text in a image."
https://github.com/Vasile-Peste/Typefont